# SOAP V2 query returns empty array

Tags: inventory, soap-api-v2, cataloginventory

This simple query works as expected with SOAP V2:

```
$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
var_dump($result);
```

but swap the Role resource access to **Catalog Inventory > Retrieve stock data**  …and substitute this instead:

```
$result = $proxy->catalogInventoryStockItemList($sessionId, array('1', '2'));
var_dump($result);
```

…and the result is:

array(0) { }

But there are plenty of products with inventory of at least 1.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Magento 1.9.2.2

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.list.html

Comment: Do you have a product with Id 1 Or Id 2?

Comment: It return result if product with id 1 and 2 exist in your catalog

Comment: Thank SH and Minesh Patel. For now, unable to test any further...as even the first simple query has stopped working! The server hosts deny changing anything. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. My situation was different in a few respects:

1. I'm using the V1 API.
2. I'm passing SKUs instead of product IDs.

Here was my original code:

```
$skus = ['SKU001', 'SKU002', 'SKU003'];
$results = $client->call(
        $sessionID,
        'cataloginventory_stock_item.list',
        $skus);
```

Just like the documentation says, right? But I was getting an empty array result, too.

When I stepped through the Magento code using the debugger, I saw that only the first SKU in my list was being passed to the API method, and passed as a string, not an array. So I wrapped my array of SKUs in another array like so:

```
$results = $client->call(
        $sessionID,
        'cataloginventory_stock_item.list',
        [$skus]);  // Note the square brackets here.
```

That solved the problem. It seems the API docs on Magento's website are just plain wrong.